# Can't login anymore after installation of Multi-tenant support for Kiwi TCMS

Tags: multi-tenant, kiwi-tcms

I had a kiwi instance running as docker containers under RHEL8 with  **kiwitcms/kiwi:latest**-image as kiwi_web container and **centos/postgresql-12-centos7**-image as kiwi_db container. Provided via reverse proxy in an existing apache.
I was able to login as the created superuser.

Then I've installed multi-tenant support via `pip install kiwitcms-tenants`.

I've set the `KIWI_TENANTS_DOMAIN` variable.

I did `podman exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py migrate` and `podman exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py refresh_permissions`.

Then I've created a tenant via `podman exec -u 0 -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py create_tenant`.

Now, if I am still logged in (from the session before installing multi-tenant support), I can now see the new Mandant plugin and the tenant configurations in the admin area.

But, if I logout, I can't login anymore. It does not say "wrong credentials" or something like that, like it appears if I put in wrong credentials. The fields are just emptied and I am simply not forwarded. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing here?

I think you are missing the fact that tenant routing is done on a domain basis. The domain which you configure with the `create_tenant` command is the one you should be using to access the multi-tenant Kiwi TCMS instance.

If `KIWI_TENANTS_DOMAIN=example.com` then you should use either `example.com` in `create_tenant` or something like `public.example.com`.  Every other tenant will be `<tenant name>.example.com`.

If that doesn't work you need to provide more information starting with your reverse proxy logs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alexander! 
It works if I just leave the name field in `create_tenant` empty. I thought `create_tenant` would create an additional domain and leave the "original" untouched.